# Html5 Div Data atribute bot showing

Tags: json, attributes

I am trying to set atributes for my div from Json, but i cannot get it to work. Writing the values manually works, but not when setting them. i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>ThingSpeak Live Colours</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var Temp;
        var Humidity;
        var Light;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/200101/feed/last.json', null, function (data) {
                Temp = data["field1"];
                Humidity = data["field2"];
                Light = data["field3"];
                var PreviewGaugeMeter_1 = document.getElementById("PreviewGaugeMeter_1");
                var Data_percent_1 = PreviewGaugeMeter_1.getAttribute("data-percent");
                PreviewGaugeMeter_1.setAttribute("data-percent", Temp);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="GaugeMeter" id="PreviewGaugeMeter_1" data-percent="" data-append="%" data-size="90" data-theme="Green-Gold-Red" data-animate_gauge_colors="1" data-animate_text_colors="1" data-width="9" data-label="" data-style="Arch" data-label_color="fff"></div>

</html>
```

And this my JSON output:

```
{"created_at":"0016-12-12T00:00:00Z","entry_id":37,"field1":" 4","field2":" 7","field3":"4"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, by getting "$.getJSON" to send variables to another webpage, from there i used $_GET, to retrieve them from the url, and it works.